# Calculating end time from a start time and a percent complete in mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

What I have:

I have a timestamp field with the time that my project started

The user is updating the project with the % complete (1 to 100 not .01 to 1)

I want to insert into an updates table with an estimated completion timestamp.

Basic math:

How to get the full time of the project:

```
(now() - start timestamp) * (100 / percent complete)
```

End Time:

```
start timestamp + full time of the project estimated above
```

I then need to insert the end time estimated into the table during the insert.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've got it.

```
select timestampadd(second, round(timestampdiff(second, '2012-08-22 22:00:30', now())*(100/33)), '2012-08-22 22:00:30');
```

that returns:
2012-08-30 17:28:41

the 33 would be the %, and the other timestamps are the start time.  Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Right away you've got a problem, never mind the math.

The [`timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) datatype automatically updates to the current time every time you touch the row. That means when "the user updates the project", the `start_timestamp` column will update too!

You need the `datetime` datatype instead, which stores the same type of data, but doesn't update when other columns are updated.

Comment: hmm, i've tested a few times, and this doesn't seem true